# How Would I Nest This MySQL Select Query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with user payment details, and another table with a list of users. I want to get the balance of all users from the payment details, but only for users that are not banned (which is a column in the users table).

I am somewhat new to nested queries so I am not sure how to do this?

Here is what I have tried so far...

```
mysql_query("
    SELECT SUM(balance) 
    FROM payment_details 
    WHERE (SELECT ban 
           FROM users 
           WHERE username=username
          ) != '1'
")
```

Note: Username is a column in both tables.

The above query does not work.

To Recap: There are two tables: payment_details and users. I want to add together the balance column for all the users that are not banned.

Comment: Is the total of all users, or do you want a total for each user?

Comment: Total for all users who are not banned :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a subquery here.  Instead, use a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT SUM(payment_details.balance) FROM payment_details
JOIN users ON payment_details.username = users.username
WHERE ban != '1'
```

Comment: It seems like this should work, but its giving me the old "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given" error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Switched it to PDO real quick because I have error handling setup. It says, "Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'balance' in field list is ambiguous' in ..."

Comment: @user1019588: Change it to `payment_details.balance`.  (Why does your users table have a `balance` field?)

Comment: Question...by using that JOIN am I able to access all columns from the users row?

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, a join is probably what you want.

However to answer the specific question, you could try a query like:

```
SELECT SUM(payment_details.balance)
    FROM payment_details
    WHERE payment_details.username in (
        SELECT users.username
            FROM users WHERE ban != '1'
    );
```

Note that it wasn't clear from the question whether you wanted the sum for each individual user, or the total sum for all users. The above query provides the latter -- not grouped by user.

Comment: This did work (after adding the ban!='1'). Is there a certain reason why JOIN is better than this?

Comment: @user1019588: `JOIN`s are more efficient than subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

the query is:

```
SELECT SUM(balance) FROM payment_details JOIN users ON payment_details.username=users.username WHERE users.ban !='1' group by payment_details.username
```

by the way, working on the users ids would be much better than on the usernames